# Rails "where" query being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I'm having a problem with a query.  I have a list of scopes in my model:

```
class Drawing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions

  scope :by_description, lambda { |description| where('description LIKE ?', "%#{description}%") unless description.nil? }
  scope :by_drawing_number, lambda { |drawing_number| where('drawing_number LIKE ?', "%#{drawing_number}%") unless drawing_number.nil? }
  scope :by_item_number, lambda { |item_number| where('item_number LIKE ?', "%#{item_number}%") unless item_number.nil? }
  scope :by_pump_model, lambda { |pump_model| where('pump_model LIKE ?', "%#{pump_model}%") unless pump_model.nil? }
  scope :by_frame_size, lambda { |frame_size| where('frame_size LIKE ?', "%#{frame_size}%") unless frame_size.nil? }
  scope :by_part_type, lambda { |part_type| where('part_type LIKE ?', "%#{part_type}%") unless part_type.nil? }
  scope :by_created_before, lambda { |created_before| where('created_at <= ?', created_before) unless created_before.nil? }
  scope :by_created_after, lambda { |created_after| where('created_at >= ?', created_after) unless created_after.nil? }
```

And I call on them in my index action in the controller:

```
  def index

    @drawings = Drawing.by_description(params[:drawings][:description]).by_drawing_number(params[:drawings][:drawing_number]).\
      by_item_number(params[:drawings][:item_number]).by_pump_model(params[:drawings][:pump_model]).by_frame_size(params[:drawings]\
      [:frame_size]).by_part_type(params[:drawings][:part_type]).by_created_before(params[:drawings][:created_before]).\
      by_created_after(params[:drawings][:created_after]).all  

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @drawings }
    end
  end
```

All of the queries work, and I can use them to filter a search by any of the given variables, except for the by_created_before and by_created_after scopes.  The params hash is showing the date that has been inputted to search, but the outputted query does not include those two scopes.  Here is a snippet of the log:

```
Started GET "/drawings?utf8=%E2%9C%93&drawings%5Bdescription%5D=&drawings%5Bdrawing_number%5D=&drawings%5Bitem_number%5D=&drawings%5Bpump_model%5D=&drawings%5Bframe_size%5D
e%5D=&drawings%5Bcreated_before%281i%29%5D=&drawings%5Bcreated_before%282i%29%5D=&drawings%5Bcreated_before%283i%29%5D=&drawings%5Bcreated_after%281i%29%5D=2013&drawings%5B
%5D=5&drawings%5Bcreated_after%283i%29%5D=2&commit=Search" for 127.6.43.1 at 2013-08-31 16:49:56 -0400                                                                      
Processing by DrawingsController#index as HTML                                                                                                                              
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "drawings"=>{"description"=>"", "drawing_number"=>"", "item_number"=>"", "pump_model"=>"", "frame_size"=>"", "part_type"=>"", "created_before(1i
re(2i)"=>"", "created_before(3i)"=>"", "created_after(1i)"=>"2013", "created_after(2i)"=>"5", "created_after(3i)"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Search"}                                
  Drawing Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "drawings".* FROM "drawings" WHERE (description LIKE '%%') AND (drawing_number LIKE '%%') AND (item_number LIKE '%%') AND (pump_model LIKE '%
IKE '%%') AND (part_type LIKE '%%')                                                                                                                                         
  Rendered drawings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.4ms)                                                                                                      
Completed 200 OK in 291ms (Views: 86.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

I've also tried just using

```
lambda {|created_before| where(:created_at <= created_before)...}
```

Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I was able to work up to solve the problem.  pdobb was right about having to either put the 3 parameters into a single string, or deal with them separately.  Here is my updated model:

```
class Drawing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions

  scope :by_description, lambda { |description| where('description LIKE ?', "%#{description}%") unless description.nil? }
  scope :by_drawing_number, lambda { |drawing_number| where('drawing_number LIKE ?', "%#{drawing_number}%") unless drawing_number.nil? }
  scope :by_item_number, lambda { |item_number| where('item_number LIKE ?', "%#{item_number}%") unless item_number.nil? }
  scope :by_pump_model, lambda { |pump_model| where('pump_model LIKE ?', "%#{pump_model}%") unless pump_model.nil? }
  scope :by_frame_size, lambda { |frame_size| where('frame_size LIKE ?', "%#{frame_size}%") unless frame_size.nil? }
  scope :by_part_type, lambda { |part_type| where('part_type LIKE ?', "%#{part_type}%") unless part_type.nil? }
  scope :by_created_before, lambda { |x,y,z| 
    d=Date.new(x.to_i, y.to_i, z.to_i)
    d.to_s
    where('created_on <= ?', d) unless d.nil? } 

  scope :by_created_after, lambda { |x,y,z| 
    d=Date.new(x.to_i, y.to_i, z.to_i)
    d.to_s
    where('created_on >= ?', d) unless d.nil? }
```

and the final action with the overall query:

```
  def index

    @drawings = Drawing.by_description(params[:drawings][:description]).by_drawing_number(params[:drawings][:drawing_number]).\
      by_item_number(params[:drawings][:item_number]).by_pump_model(params[:drawings][:pump_model]).by_frame_size(params[:drawings]\
      [:frame_size]).by_part_type(params[:drawings][:part_type]).by_created_before(params[:drawings]['created_before(1i)'], params[:drawings]['created_before(2i)'], params[:drawings]['created_before(3i)']).\
      by_created_after(params[:drawings]['created_after(1i)'], params[:drawings]['created_after(2i)'], params[:drawings]['created_after(3i)']).all  

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @drawings }
    end
  end
```

I know this isn't the most elegant query since I end up with very long URLs, but it's working and correctly querying my model.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `created_at` and `created_before` params are coming in via multiple params -- see the `Parameters:` section in your log there. The month, day, and year come in on special `(2i)`, `(3i)`, and `(1i)` params. This is typical of the `date_select` helper. When using mass assignment, rails would put that date back together into a single string for you like you were expecting here... but here you'll have to do it yourself.

A quick suggestion:

If this is the only way you're going to be consuming the date from the form, use [`select_date` instead of `date_select`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#barebones-helpers) as the params will be much easier to understand and parse back together again into a single date string. Or, just use a `text_field` if possible. In conjunction with a date-select UI (calendar interface, or whatever) this isn't as bad as it seems -- and it has the advantage of not seeming to allow invalid dates such as February 31st.

All in all, you just need to figure out which of the params are which and interpolate them into a date-looking string before passing into your scopes and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

"The params hash is showing the date that has been inputted to search".

Where is it showing this?

If I decode the parameters in a URL decoder I get "/drawings?utf8=✓&drawings[description]=&drawings[drawing_number]=&drawings[ite‌​m_number]=&drawings[pump_model]=&drawings[frame_size] e]=&drawings[created_before(1i)]=&drawings[created_before(2i)]=&drawings[created‌​_before(3i)]=&drawings[created_after(1i)]=2013&drawings[ ]=5&drawings[created_after(3i)]=2&commit=Search"

After fixing the input, you have to convert the strings to dates before doing a compare in the database. Something like Datetime.parse params[:drawings][:created_before]